# Do I need back-end and database for single page app using Facebook Connect?

Tags: database, facebook, backend, frontend

I want to create a one page site that will use Facebook Connect and allow my friends to reserve a spot for an upcoming event. Using there Facebook ID I would like my friends to pay(reserve) a spot and then show their Facebook picture in the spot they reserved. Sort of like Meetup.com when you RSVP except its a one page site and for a one time event. Can I build this only using front-end technologies or do I need a backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **yes**, you will need a back end system to store the paid registrants, print out a list of paid users to have at the door of the event to make sure they paid, store the user id to be able to display their picture, etc. etc. etc.